# How to get user object with belongs_to in ember js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have two models `Recipe` and `User`. I can't get the user object in recipe. What am I doing wrong?

```
App.Recipe.find(1).get('title') // Returns "recipe01 title". All works fine.

App.Recipe.find(1).get('user') // Returns null
```

user.js.coffee

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
   email: DS.attr('string')
   recipes: DS.hasMany('App.Recipe')
```

recipe.js.coffee

```
App.Recipe = DS.Model.extend
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
  title: DS.attr('string')
```

my json array

```
{
  recipe: {
    id: 1,
    title: "recipe01",
    user: {
      id: 1,
      name: "ejiqpep",
      email: "ejiqpep@gmail.com",
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Ember Data expects dependent records to be referenced by key. Then you can either sideload the extra records or let Ember lazy load them from their API endpoint.

```
{
  recipe: {
    id: 1,
    title: "recipe01",
    user_id: 1
  },
  user: {
    id: 1,
    name: "ejiqpep",
    email: "ejiqpep@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

However, you can also instruct the Adapter that the records are embedded.

There are two types of embedded record loading `embedded: 'always'`, where Ember will both receive and send any changes with the objects embedded.

```
App.Adapter.map 'App.Recipe',
  user: 
    embedded: 'always'
```

Or `embedded:'load'` where Ember will load embedded objects from JSON but will save changes back to the API as separate objects.

```
App.Adapter.map 'App.Recipe',
  user:
    embedded: 'load'
```

Which of the three options you'd like to take is up to you.
Embedded objects have only recently been implemented and there are a couple of issues around them (see the Ember-Data issues on Github), but will work without any changes to your existing server.